# How to make ALL ports accessible on CentOS 5.6?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-forwarding, linux-networking, node.js

I've set up a CentOS 5.6 development server running as a virtual machine under Virtual PC 2007, in order to have a play with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Everything is up and running, but I can't seem to access port 8234, which is the port the Node server is running on.

I know the server is running because I can `wget localhost:8234` and retrieve an HTML file containing 'Hello World', which is correct.

If I use a port scanner, I can see that all the ports mentioned in the Allow Incoming section are open and responding to pings, but nothing else.

I've run `setup` and set things as follows:

[image: Firewall Config]

[image: Port Config]

To my mind, these settings should have turned off the firewall and be allowing anything that comes in on `eth0` (the sole virtual network interface), but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I just disable the firewall completely, or failing that, make port 8234 accessible to the outside world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your webserver is bound to localhost, only.**

Make sure your webserver is listening on an IP address other than localhost (127.0.0.1) or link-local (169.254.*.*)

`netstat -tl` will help

Answer (score 6):

The `system-config-securitylevel-tui` application provides *VERY* limited control over the host firewall. If you want to disable the firewall completely you should do:

```
chkconfig iptables off
service iptables stop
```

That will stop the firewall from starting at runlevel changes, and shut it down if it's currently running.

To allow access to your single port

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -m tcp --dport 8234 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Comment: The guy could also have enter the actual port in the screen under "other ports" with: 

tcp:8234

Comment: @Rilindo Fair point. TBH, since I haven't used the config tool in anything approaching recent memory I didn't actually think of it.

Comment: But you are right it is fairly limited - you can open or close ports, but you can't do nat or significant filtering based on protocols or source/destination . Either you will need to do by hand or use the Red Hat's firewall configurator (in RHEL6, at least).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to customize the firewall if it's disabled. I believe you can also turn off the firewall once installation has completed; I don't have a CentOS system handy to look it up but the Internet seems to recommend

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

This will save your rules, and disable the firewall on subsequent boot. There's probably also a graphical tool, this being Red Hat we're talking about. ;)

A firewall is a decent thing to have. You would add 8234:tcp to the other ports field (and/or udp if your service needs it).

Running the iptables command provided by @Lucas will work but doesn't disable the firewall, just allows all traffic. In which case, there's not too much point in leaving the firewall running.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

as root

Comment: This doesn't seem to have made any difference. Do I need to restart the firewall service, or anything else?

Comment: @Mark IIRC restarting the firewall removes any custom settings, so no. But if this doesn't work, then the firewall isn't the issue here

Comment: @TheLQ it does unless you save them first, when they get stored in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` or somewhere thereabouts. The distro-approved method is to use commands to modify the config then save the running config.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to see what port your web server is listening on

(I am assuming that you are using apache)

netstat -an | grep httpd

Make sure that it is bound to your public IP and not just the local loopback